# label every decade in colorbar for log imshow

Tags: python, logging, matplotlib

I want to plot some data in a matrix. The colors = z-values are logarithmic. My Problem is that only some of the ticks are labeled. To be precise "1e1, 1e10, ...". If those values are outside the data range there are no labels at all (but ticks). I want to have labels for every decade ie "1e1, 1e2, 1e3, ..." and also "1e-1, 1e-2, ...".
Here comes a minimal example:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

data = numpy.loadtxt("data.txt")
pylab.imshow(data, interpolation="nearest", origin="upper", aspect="equal", norm=LogNorm())
cbar = pylab.colorbar()
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `set_ticks` method of `matplotlib.axis.Axis`. It's [documented here.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axis_api.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried implementing it. However this gives me a garbled colorbar and warnings/errors whenever I move the cursor accross the plot. I assume that I would have to pass only the ticks that are contained in the data range, but calculating this seems nontrivial (stretching the scale because of a single extreme point would render the log-scaling useless). So there should be a more elegant way, right?